# o365 security and compliance searching for subsite name/url change

Tags: sharepoint-online, auditing

After an unrequested change I am now using the compliance and security reports to identify who changed a subsite name.

Anybody have experience with it? the audits find nothing if I search for 'rename site'.

Comment: I have not been impressed with the auditing capability of the compliance center, it seemingly only reports sharing/permissions related things. I've yet to see it accurately pull file level results.

Comment: yeah but in my case 'rename site' seems pretty straightforward, or it might mean something else?

Comment: Anything SharePoint related that is not permission related, I've yet to see in the compliance center audit reports, I would advise opening a ticket with Microsoft support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft told me to search instead of Renamed Site, Renamed FILE and yes it was there. There is an inaccuracy on this particular action so Rename Site will never display anything (as of today), while the action site rename is logged under 'renamed file'. Hopefully they will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

[SiteRenamed](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Search-the-audit-log-in-the-Office-365-Security-Compliance-Center-0d4d0f35-390b-4518-800e-0c7ec95e946c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1#siteadminactivities) is an activity that is logged in the Security & Compliance center. It may take 30 minutes to 24 hours for a particular activity to be logged, however.

Comment: i have checked again 22 hours later and still no log of site renamed. in the same timespan i have created a site collection and immediately it appeared

Comment: Did they change the title or the URL?